# How to declare a dependency on a shared library in setup.py?

Tags: python

In my code, I use `ctypes.CDLL` to load a shared library:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL("my_fast_lib.so")
```

This library is written in Go, which I build separately.

How do I declare this dependency in my `setup.py`?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be fully handled by the Python distribution system.  ([This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843765/setup-py-check-if-non-python-library-dependency-exists) is similar to yours.)  Things like `pip` only care about dependencies they can install, and if `pip` doesn't know how to install a Go lib, it doesn't care about it.  If you have to install it separately anyway, what would you gain by making it a dependency?

Comment: @BrenBarn I have to build and install it separately just because I don't know how to build it with my Python package. In the documentation, I could only find examples of building C/C++ extensions, but I have no idea how to do the same thing for Go.